# Lake Maps with changing water levels

Tags: lakes

Lots of people crash boats and get injured or die every year because of underwater hazards. I'm trying to design lake maps where the topography and data points change with the water level. Any idea on where to begin with this?

Comment: What program are you using? What data do you have access to?  Paper map? Online app? 
Please provide more information !

Comment: Do you have any bathymetry data for your lake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a bathymetry data for of the particular lake.  This is, simply put, the elevation data of the lake's bottom.  Ideally, the bathymetry data will form a basin showing the "terrain" characteristics of the lake bottom.

This type of data is hard to get, at least here in Northwestern Ontario, Canada where we have ~ 250,000 lakes.  Some government navigational maps exist that provide bathymetry derived contour maps for marine navigation purposes but this is, in our area at least, limited to the Great Lakes and a few large inland lakes. The available data is also not very detailed.

Usually an actual survey is necessary to obtain this data. The uquiptment needed usually involves a sonar and a GPS and a boat on which this equitpment is mounted.  Boat with equitpment follows a patern on a predetermined grid. XYZ data is then extracted, cleaned up and interpolated to produce a Raster or vector surface.  It's actually not as complicated as it sounds, just time -consuming;  I was able to hook-up a fish-finder (sonar) with a Garmin GPS to do this on a small scale.

I belelive there are some remote sensing techniques that can deliver bathymetry data but the type of sensing needs to penetrate water surface. To an extent this may be able to be done with stereo-imagery where the image captured penetrates water surface and features on the bottom area clearly visible allowing for typical stereo-imagery triangulation. I am only aware of bathymetry data collected with a sonar of some type so I don't know whether using stereo imagery can actually be used. Probably only in shallow areas. Image penetration may be increased by using a circular polarizer which can remove glare from water surface.

**When you have bathymetry data and a resulting raster surface then it's just a matter of a cut and fill (or similar) calculation**: one input will be a flat surface plane representing the surface at a specified elevation, second input will be the bathymetry surface itself. In ArcGIS, the resulting calculation generates an output of cut and filled areas where the "cut" areas would in this case represent bathymetry features that rise above the surface when it's lowered.  The more you lower the water surface the more "cut" areas will be revealed that represent the new shoreline at lower water levels and new potential hazards that "rise-up" from the bottom.

In ArcGIS the [Cut Fill tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_Cut_Fill_works/009z000000vt000000/) can do this but there are other similar methods.

An example of data (visualized in 3D) from my own bathymetry survey using a fish finder and a Garmin GPS:

[image]

AN example of bathymetry data supplied by a surveyor:
[image]